# Getting value from preferences?

Tags: java, android

I have one check box in preferences and I get value

```
SharedPreferences myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

my check box from preferences is checked by default and I'm using this

```
if(myPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true)
```

to check if user change check box state. If condition from above is true I'll get notification in status bar(I will not present code for notification and service).
So, my problem is that I'm not getting notification until I click on preferences, then finally my PreferenceManager get value from check box and my notification trigger.
How can I fix that?
Thanks, Wolf.

Answer (score 2):

Your checkbox might be default "true", but your setting isn't. If your setting hasn't been set at all, you get the default from your `getBoolean`, which is `false`. You are probably looking for this:

```
if(myPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox", true) == true)
```

which says: if you can't find the preference (yet), use the default, which is `true`.

Comment: Hey sorry for delay, that didn't solve my problem.
Again I get notification only when I enter preferences activity.